# Linq - EF : How to query a Junction table?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use c#, linq and EF4.

I have two tables in my DataBase represented in my Conceptual Model:

DataBase Tables:

```
CmsContents
CmsRelatedContents (Junction table)
```

Entity Type:

```
CmsContent
```

I have some Navigational Properties:

```
for CmsContent --> CmsContents --> Return Collection of CmsContent --> from role: CmsContent1 to CmsContent (map ToContentId)
for CmsContent --> CmsContents1 --> Return Collection of CmsContent --> from role: CmsContent to CmsContent1 (map FromContentId)
```

Data in DataBase for the Junction Table (CmsRelatedContents) is presented:

```
FromContentId   ToContentId
4               3
5               2
```

In table CmsContents:

```
ContentId
2
3
4
5
```

I need use Linq or EF to retrieve `Objects in CmsContent` associated in the `ToContentId` column filtering the Junction table for a specific `FromContentId`

Do you have an idea how to do it?

Please provide me sample of code. Thanks for your help on this!

---

EDIT : SOLUTION

```
// Option A:
           var test = from cnt in context.CmsContents
                       where cnt.CmsContents.Any(t => t.ContentId == contentId)
                       select cnt;

// Option B: 
       var toContents = context.CmsContents.Where(r => r.CmsContents.Any(t => t.ContentId == contentId));
```

Thanks guys from your support!

Comment: And what did you try? Questions like *Give me some codez plz?* are not popular especially if you don't show anything you tried.

Comment: I tried this var toContents = context.CmsContents.FirstOrDefault(cnt => cnt.ContentId == contentId && cnt.CmsContents1.Any(from => from.ContentId == contentId)).CmsContents.Any();

Comment: but was not working, thanks for your previously comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if i understood you correctly but this might be what you need:

`dbContext.CmsContent.Where(r => r.CmsContents.Any(t => t.Id = someId))`

Comment: Could you please point me out some resource about your technic? so I can read more about it? thanks